# Can't update ballot date in UpdateView in django

Tags: python, django

I designed a model:

```
class Sitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ballot_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = TreeForeignKey('Genre', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)

    def get_cut_off_date(self):
        return self.sit_date - timedelta(days=16)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cut_off_date = self.get_cut_off_date()
        self.ballot_date = self.get_ballot_date()
        super(Sitting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It correctly set ballot_date and cut_off_date. When I try to update the ballot date in UpdateView it was saved but no changes made in the database. I also tried it in django admin panel result was same.

[image]

Suppose I want to change ballot date from 20 august to 22 august, I can made it in the form and also save it but when call the sitting no changes are found.

I believe it was the reason of

```
def get_ballot_date(self):
            return self.sit_date - timedelta(days=12)
```

Can anybody suggest the ways how could I overwrite above function so that it accepted later changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly override the ballot_date and cut_off_date fields every time you save. If you don't want that, maybe you need to put a check there?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.cut_off_date:
        self.cut_off_date = self.get_cut_off_date()
    if not self.ballot_date:
        self.ballot_date = self.get_ballot_date()
```